# Xdebug profiler not writing files

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, profiler, xdebug-profiler

I'm using MAMP, and I have xdebug enabled in the extensions tab. Debugging works fine, but the profiler doesn't write to any files.

**php.ini**

```
[xdebug]
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.20/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0;
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1;
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/Users/jordyvandomselaar/workspace/xdebug/profiler/snapshots"
```

I have the xdebug extension, and it's toggle on "profiler". I've `chmod`ded the output folder to `777` to be sure it's not a permission issue.

Anything I missed?

Answer (score 2):

if this your actual configuration is, then you deactivated the extension with the semicolon at the beginning of this line:

```
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.20/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so"
```

remove the starting semicolon and restart your apache server

Comment: It's weird though, because debugging does work, and It's turned on in the MAMP settings.

Comment: @g3mini If it work s.. then you may also have another config file elsewhere. I suggest to grab `phpinfo()` output and check 2 things: 1) the top (very first) table with general PHP info -- it will tell what config file(s) were loaded 2) dedicated xdebug section -- will tell your current config.